# Update a Date to a specific month

Tags: c#, datetime

In my MVC application, my users said that they do written tests 2 times a year.. in March and September.  However, if a user fails a test then they retest in 90 days (doesn't have to be March or September).

For example, if a user takes **their very first test** on `3/2/2016`, and that user passes, then that user doesn't need to take the other test until anyday in September.  But if that user fails, then that user needs to retake the test on the 31st of May.  So let me try and illustrate this with a little bit of code.

```
DateTime usersTestDate = new DateTime(2016, 3, 2);
// user fails
usersTestDate = usersTestDate.AddDays(90);
// usersTestDate is now 5/31/2016

// now the user retakes the test and passes

// usersTestDate should now be in September of 2016.
```

How do I get that to happen, since usersTestDate could essentially be any date in the book if the user fails.. Basically, if the user passes a retake of the exam in any months besides March or September.. how do I get their new date to be in either March or September?

I have created a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hxW1WS)

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

If they fail again after already failing once, then they keep retaking every 90 days. If they keep failing their March test past September then they skip September and just go to March again if they pass

Comment: what happens when they fail a second time?  Do they try again?  What happens when they keep failing their March test past September?

Comment: @Jonesopolis sorry i didn't add that. if they fail again after already failing once, then they keep retaking every 90 days. If they keep failing their March test past September then they skip September and just go to March again if they pass

Comment: It sounds like you have a decent idea of the requirements, are you just confused on how to translate that english into the code?

Comment: So look at the month of the current test and work ahead from there. If the current month passed is May then increase it to September, otherwise, increase it to March. (ie, student passes on 5/31/2016 5 is greater than 3 so month should be 9. If however the student passes on 11/15/2016 then you would need to set the month to 3 (March) and increase the year because they're after both months and the next test month falls in the next year.

Comment: @Jonesopolis haha that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (userTestDate.Month < 3)
  userTestDate = new DateTime(userTestDate.Year, 3, 1); 
else if (userTestDate.Month < 9)
  userTestDate = new DateTime(userTestDate.Year, 9, 1);
else
  userTestDate = new DateTime(userTestDate.Year + 1, 3, 1);
```

You don't specify which day of the month the March & September dates should be, so I have arbitrarily chosen the first.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I definitely made this out to be a lot harder than what it needed to be!

Answer (score 1):

I think this captures what you're after.  I set the next test date to the last day in Sept/March, although you could easily change that based on your requirements.

```
public DateTime GetNextTestDate(DateTime testDate, bool passed)
{
    if (passed)
    {
        if (testDate.Month >= 3 && testDate.Month < 9)
            return new DateTime(testDate.Year, 9, 30);
        else
            return new DateTime(testDate.Year + (testDate.Month >= 9 && testDate.Month <= 12 ? 1 : 0), 3, 31);  // (add a year if we're 9-12)
    }
    else
        return testDate.AddDays(90);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I definitely made this out to be a lot harder than what it needed to be!

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the logic consider the following.

When someone passes, we do not need to care about the last test date; we can just schedule them for the next available test, based off the current date.  The code below says you can only book for that test the month before

If they fail, then add 90 days to the last test date.

```
public DateTime NextTestDate(DateTime testDate, bool passed)
{
    if (passed)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        if (DateTime.Now.Month < 3)
            return new DateTime(now.Year, 3, 2);
        if (DateTime.Now.Month < 9)
            return new DateTime(now.Year, 9, 2);
        return new DateTime(now.Year + 1, 3, 2); 
    }
    return testDate.AddDays(90);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I definitely made this out to be a lot harder than what it needed to be!